# How to calculate sum field in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Please, take a look on example http://jsfiddle.net/6h1ok6g6/1/

```
var data = [
    {shop:"shop1", day:"2015-11-1",document:"1", sell:"50",profit:"10",percent:"25"},
    {shop:"shop1", day:"2015-11-1",document:"1", sell:"15",profit:"5",percent:"50"},
    {shop:"shop1", day:"2015-11-2",document:"23", sell:"10",profit:"2",percent:"25"},
    {shop:"shop1", day:"2015-11-2",document:"23", sell:"20",profit:"5",percent:"33"},
    {shop:"shop1", day:"2015-11-3",document:"45", sell:"50",profit:"10",percent:"25"},
    {shop:"shop1", day:"2015-11-3",document:"45", sell:"20",profit:"10",percent:"100"},
    {shop:"shop2", day:"2015-11-1",document:"3", sell:"50",profit:"10",percent:"25"},
    {shop:"shop2", day:"2015-11-1",document:"3", sell:"15",profit:"5",percent:"50"},
    {shop:"shop2", day:"2015-11-2",document:"13", sell:"10",profit:"2",percent:"25"},
    {shop:"shop2", day:"2015-11-2",document:"13", sell:"20",profit:"5",percent:"33"},
    {shop:"shop2", day:"2015-11-3",document:"25", sell:"50",profit:"10",percent:"25"},
    {shop:"shop2", day:"2015-11-3",document:"25", sell:"20",profit:"10",percent:"100"}
           ];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: data,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                rowNum: 200000,
                colModel: [
                { label: 'shop', name: 'shop', width:300 },
                { label: 'day', name: 'day'},
                { label: 'document', name: 'document'},
                { label: 'sell', name: 'sell', width: 90, sorttype:'number', formatter:"number", summaryType:'sum'},
                { label: 'profit', name: 'profit', width: 90, sorttype:'number', formatter:"number", summaryType:'sum'},
                { label: 'percent', name: 'percent', width: 90, sorttype:'number',formatter:"number" }
                ],
                viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
                caption: "test",
                footerrow: true,
                grouping:true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['shop','day','document'],
        groupColumnShow : [true,false,false],
        groupSummary : [true,true,false],
        groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>','<b>{0}</b>','<b>{0}</b>'],
        groupCollapse : true,
        groupOrder: ['asc','asc','asc'],
        //showSummaryOnHide: false,
        groupDataSorted : true,
        groupSummaryPos: ['header','header','header']
    }
});
```

There is column "percent" which i can calculate by formula: profit*100/(sell-profit)
I'm doing it for any row, but how can i make this operation for summary rows?

Average summary type is not correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found sollution [here](http://guriddo.net/?kbe_knowledgebase=customized-aggregations-in-grouping)

```
{ label: 'percent', name: 'percent', width: 90,sorttype:'number',formatter:"number",    
summaryType : function(value, name, record) {
      // initialize the value object
      if(typeof value === 'string'){
         value = {totalAmount: 0, totalProfit: 0 };
      }
      // perform summary
      if(record['sell']) {

         value.totalAmount += parseFloat(record['sell']);

      }
      if(record['profit']) {

        value.totalSebest += parseFloat(record['profit']);

      }
      return value;
   },
   formatter: function (cellval, opts, rwdat, act) {
     // get the regional options and pass it to the custom formatter
     opts = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.getRegional(this, 'formatter') , opts);
     // determine if we are in summary row to put the value
     if (opts.rowId === '') {
        if(cellval.totalAmount > 0) {
           var val = (cellval.totalAmount - cellval.totalProfit)/cellval.totalProfit*100;
           return $.fn.fmatter('number', val, opts, rwdat, act)+'%';
        } else {
           return '0';
        }
     } else {
         return $.fn.fmatter('number', cellval, opts, rwdat, act);
     }
  }
```